# Function will log value but return undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, return, undefined

The function below will log the value of `newData` but returns `undefined` when called. Does anyone know why this might be? Also, any feedback on the function itself would be greatly appreciated!

```
export const filterByDateTimeRange = (data=[{}], timeKey=[], startTime=moment(), stopTime=moment()) => {
  let newData = [];
  let i = 0;
  for(const item of data) {
    let time;
    let index = 0
    timeKey.map(key => {
      time ? time = time[key] : time = item[key];
      index++
      if(index === timeKey.length) {
        if(moment(time).isBetween(startTime, stopTime, undefined, '[)')) {
          newData.push(item)
        };
        i++;
        if(i === data.length) {
          console.log(newData);
          return (newData);
        }
      }
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: You never actually return newData.  You map it, but never return it.  Note that returning in the mapping method doesn't count.  Map returns a new array with the values you return within it taking the place of the original array's members.  But as stated, you never do anything with it.

Comment: If you just added `return newData;` before the last brace, I'm pretty sure your code would work as you intend it to.  That said though, I wouldn't use `.map()` when you never actually use the result; I'd use `.forEach()` for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `map` function is usually used to transform a collection and store the results, for example:

```
var squares = [2, 3, 4].map(x => { return x * x });
// result is squares = [4, 9, 16]
```

The `forEach` function is more appropriate to use here since you just want to loop over the array and don't care about storing a transformation.

Then when the outer loop finishes your function can return `newData`

```
export const filterByDateTimeRange = (data=[{}], timeKey=[], startTime=moment(), stopTime=moment()) => {
  let newData = [];
  let i = 0;
  for(const item of data) {
    let time;
    let index = 0
    timeKey.forEach(key => {                         //changed to a forEach loop
      time ? time = time[key] : time = item[key];
      index++
      if(index === timeKey.length) {
        if(moment(time).isBetween(startTime, stopTime, undefined, '[)')) {
          newData.push(item)
        };
        i++;
        if(i === data.length) {
          console.log(newData);
        }
      }
    });
  }
  return newData; //add the return after your loop finishes
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This return inside a map function. Not return of filterByDateTimeRange(). If you want to return newData. Replace map function by for loop.

Map: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map